# Self-study assignment gone wrong. (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Word1 = input("Please type a word: ")
Word2 = input("Please type a word: ")
if len(Word1) + len(Word2)> 30:
    print("Words are to long")
    # exit -- Gotten rid of.
30 - (len(Word1) + len(Word2) == DotAmount
 print (Word1 + "."*DotAmount + Word2) # This line is causing the problem
```

I can't seem to crack this.
Anyone want to help?

EDIT: This program asks the user for 2 words, then prints them with the dot symbol (.) in between them so that 30 characters are printed.
If anyone has a better way to write this program, feel free to add it.
Opened through CMD the error is

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The pointer is pointing to print.

Comment: There's no `exit` statement. Sometimes there's an object called `exit` that you can call to exit the interpreter, but that's more for convenience at an interactive prompt.

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. Don't indent the last line.

Comment: Tip for self-study: “This line is causing the problem” – *Which* problem? You should tell us what the problem is and when there is an error, tell us the exact error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want to assign the value of

```
30 - (len(Word1) + len(Word2)) ## note that you were also missing a closing paren
```

to the name `DotAmount`.

The python syntax to do this is

```
 name = value
```

so you want

```
DotAmount =  30 - (len(Word1) + len(Word2))
```

For information, `a == b` checks to see whether `a` equals `b` and returns `True` or `False` which, in this case, is thrown away.

Comment: @user2623755: Unindent your last line and try again.

Comment: Same error, on the same line.

Comment: @user2623755: that seems unlikely.  You'd get that error, as this answer points out, if you were missing a closing parenthesis.  Did you forget to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted?

e.g., if `Word1 = "test1"`
and `Word2 = "test2"`
the output
`test1....................test2` ?

```
import sys
Word1 = input("Please type a word: ")
Word2 = input("Please type a word: ")
if len(Word1) + len(Word2)> 30:
    print("Words are to long")
    # exit -- Gotten rid of.
    sys.exit()

sDots = "." * (30 - len(Word1) - len(Word2))
print(Word1 + sDots + Word2)
```